# shrink parents widgets after child size changed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How can I make all widgets shrink, if one of their children changed height?
They expand if new height is bigger, but don't shrink if smaller.

I tried `updateGeometry()`, but it changed nothing.

Here is example, after child element shran, parents' height don't change:
[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # inner widget
        self.widget = QGroupBox('inner')
        vbox_inner = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        button1 = QPushButton('100')
        button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_height(100))
        vbox_inner.addWidget(button1)
        button2 = QPushButton('200')
        button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_height(200))
        vbox_inner.addWidget(button2)

        # outer layout
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.widget)

    # resizing element
    def change_height(self, height):
        self.widget.setFixedHeight(height)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = MainWindow()
myapp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there any way to adjust all parents widgets?

**answer** in Python:

```
widget = self.parent()
while widget:
    widget.adjustSize()
    widget = widget.parent()
```

Comment: You can try to run parent widget's [minimumSizeHint](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint) function and the resize your parent widget with returned size.

Comment: It is the way, but it seems, that `adjustSize()` make it automatically (get size hint and resize)

Comment: Yeah, seems so. I wasn't aware of that, so +1 to answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should call the [`adjustSize()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#adjustSize) method on your "toplevel" widget (your `MainWindow` in this case).

You'll need to propagate that call up the widget hierarchy yourself for more complex layouts than your sample. In C++, you could do something like this:

```
QWidget *w = <the widget you resized>->parentWidget();
while (w) {
  w->adjustSize();
  w = w->parentWidget();
}
```

Comment: It works, but I should `adjustSize` to every parent from small to big. So I need to make recursive function, that check if element have parent `.parent()`, and if it have, `adjustSize` and check its parent. Is it the right way?

Comment: no, call `adjustSize` only on the highest-level widget (the one that contains all the other ones). it should go down the widget hierarchy by itself.

Comment: It does not. If we add one more widget between them, then it only works if `adjustSize` it before `adjustSize` top level widget.

Comment: hum... you are right, I didn't test that properly. So you'll need to propagate this yourself. I added a `C++` way of doing that - sorry I don't know python well enough. (No need for recursion.)